# Looking for help to ask a parental control question about Xbox One

Tags: support, asking

Could you help me to start on the right foot?

First time posting a question here. I would like to make a question as a gamer parent. While I have several answers on other SE sites only very few of my questions are well received.

I'm having problems to make Xbox One parental controls work as I expected. I searched on https://stackexchange.com for related questions but I did't find one that fits exactly what I'm looking for but found I found some questions from this site. These questions are about the basic setup already described on the Xbox help center on the web:

- [How to stop my child from creating new accounts on Xbox One?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/262122/115285)
- [How can I set up Xbox One parental controls?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/292913/115285)

Here is what I think to ask.

> ---
>
> #### How to fix Xbox One parental controls?
>
> Tl;dr: I'm looking for instructions for/how to fix the Xbox One parental controls setup to make that my kid require to ask for more screen time rather than setting a time limit / schedule allowed time.
>
> ---
>
> I don't know how but all the members of my Microsoft Live Family were removed, so this Monday I added them again, and repeated the procedure to setup the parental control on the console including locking the creation of new accounts and setting up a guest key.
>
> The setup for Monday, time limit 4 hours, from 4 pm to 8 pm, work fine.
>
> The setup for yesterday (Tuesday, as well as other days of the week) was blocked the whole day and I was expecting that my kid send me a "more screen time" request but but they were able to play without sending it.
>
> How do I fix this?
>
> [image: Device Limits and block schedule]
>
> Related
>
> - [How to stop my child from creating new accounts on Xbox One?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/262122/115285)
> - [How can I set up Xbox One parental controls?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/292913/115285)
>
> ---
>
> **Tags:** [xbox-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-one), [xbox-live](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-live)
>
> ---

Comment: I just changed the Time limit drop-downs from `Blocked` to `Max Schedule`. I will wait for my kid to try to use their Xbox to see if that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question seems good to me, I'd say go ahead and post it on the main site. The only thing I'd change is I'd be more specific in your question title. How about something like:

#### Why isn't parental controls blocking gameplay on days it should be blocked?

<sub>Note: You also have a duplicate 'but' in the last paragraph :)</sub>

Comment: Thanks. I posted my question. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/357183/115285